# React: Pass index to children and let the array use this index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please find the sandbox for your reference if it's more convenient for you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-lichterman-k5hh6

I made a `Person` component.

In the component there's an array, and i would like to pass the index from `App` to `Person`, and it will show the person's name and age.

```
function Person(props) {
  const { info, setInfo, index } = props;

  const peopleInfo = {
    members: [
      {
        name: "Iris",
        age: 23
      },
      {
        name: "Bob",
        age: 33
      },
      {
        name: "Ken",
        age: 28
      },
      {
        name: "Eddie",
        age: 26
      }
    ]
  };

  const getInfo = () => {
    setInfo({
      name: peopleInfo.members[index].name,
      age: peopleInfo.members[index].age
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getInfo();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="card_body">
        <span className="name">{info.name}: </span>
        <span className="age">age {info.age}</span>
        <span> (index: {index})</span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Person;
```

In the `App.js`, I import two `Person` and pass the index.

```
import Person from "./components/Person.js";

function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({ name: "", age: "" });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Person info={info} setInfo={setInfo} index={0} />
      <Person info={info} setInfo={setInfo} index={3} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the example I passed `index={0}` and `index={3}` to `Person`

my ideal result should be:

Iris: age 23 (index: 0)

Eddie: age 26 (index: 3)

but the result was like this:

Eddie: age 26 (index: 0)

Eddie: age 26 (index: 3)

The index did passed to `Person` but it doesn't show the person correctly.

What can i do to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: You've only a single `info` state, so the last `Person` component to set it is the `info` that's displayed across all `Person` components. It's not really clear why you are leaking `peopleInfo` array data out to the parent or what your *actual* use-case is to even provide an answer. Can you explain more about your use-case? What problem is this code solving for?

Comment: Good day, Drew. I see. I moved the ```info``` state to ```Person``` and it's solved. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You are using a single `info` state that all `Person` components are updating when they mount, so the last `Person` component rendered and updating the state is the state that is passed ***back*** to each `Person` and displayed.

## Solution

It's a bit unclear why the `peopleInfo` is in `Person` and sent to parent component only to be passed back in. Simply consume the `index` in `Person` and conditionally render the UI if a user's info was found by index. There's no need to store any info in a state variable nor any effect to update the state.

```
function Person(props) {
  const { index } = props;

  const info = peopleInfo.members[index];

  return info ? (
    <div className="card_body">
      <span className="name">{info.name}: </span>
      <span className="age">age {info.age}</span>
      <span> (index: {index})</span>
    </div>
  ) : null;
}
```

[image]

## Demo

[image: Edit react-pass-index-to-children-and-let-the-array-use-this-index]

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you want to map through the array and print all of them with their index, if like that, then the way you are doing it is wrong, you have to it like this:

```js
//Person.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function Person(props) {
  const { name, age, index } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <div className="card_body">
        <span className="name">{name}: </span>
        <span className="age">age {age}</span>
        <span> (index: {index})</span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Person;



//App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Person from "./components/Person.js";

function App() {
  const peopleInfo = {
    members: [
      {
        name: "Iris",
        age: 23
      },
      {
        name: "Bob",
        age: 33
      },
      {
        name: "Ken",
        age: 28
      },
      {
        name: "Eddie",
        age: 26
      }
    ]
  };

  const [info, setInfo] = useState({ name: "", age: "" });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {peopleInfo.members.map((person, index) => {
        return <Person {...person} index={index} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

also udpated your sandbox [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-sky-64ccy?file=/src/App.js)